# Export button cannot be clicked on HTML page with VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm automating an HR webpage (where you have to login to see info, so I can't share access), however, after getting the query I want, I can't click a specific button. Code for that button is:

```
<div class="fbutton">
    <div>
        <span class="export_xls" style="padding-left: 20px;">Exportar XLS</span>
```

Class Name is "export_xls"

OutterText, InnerText and InnerHTML is the same: "Exportar XLS"

I have tried many things, like going into loop on every "div" or "span" object and match one of the elements I mentioned earlier and click it if found, no one is even recognizing the "Exportar XLS" text.

My code is the following:

```
Sub extraer_horarios()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim Element As HTMLLinkElement
Dim IeDoc As Object, post As Object, elem As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

URL = "http://201.122.64.119:40/accounts/login/?next=/data/worktable/"
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate URL

WaitFor IE

IE.Document.all.Item("id_username").innerText = "*****"
IE.Document.all.Item("id_password").innerText = "*****"
IE.Document.all.Item("id_login").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Set IE = GetIE("http://201.122.64.119:40/data/worktable/")
IE.navigate "http://201.122.64.119:40/page/att/AttReport/"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

IE.Document.all.Item("LEReport").Click
IE.Document.all.Item("id_cometime").Value = "2019-08-01"
IE.Document.all.Item("id_endtime").Value = "2019-08-31"
IE.Document.all.Item("id_drop_emp").Click
IE.Document.GetElementbyID("id_per_count").Focus
AppActivate "BioTime"
Application.SendKeys "{END}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Dim cBox As Object
Set cBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("chk_selected_all")(0)
cBox.Click
IE.Document.all.Item("id_close").Click
IE.Document.all.Item("id_query").Click 'Until here everrything works fine

'Here the problem starts
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
    If MyHTML_Element.innerText = "Exportar XLS" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

End Sub
```

If you want any other part of the code or something I can facilitate other than the impossiblity of sharing the access to webpage, please ask me so. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need to wait before searching for the element to click?  What does the previous click do?

Comment: It clicks a "search" button that brings up a table with selected options. "id_per_count" opens a pop-up, sendkeys choose the last option which is 200 entries per page and chk_slected_all checks a checkbox to get all the options on the query, id_close closes the pop-up that opened before. It doesn't matter if query brings data or not, button behavior is the same when manually clicked.

Comment: But you need to wait for the search to complete before you look for the download element.  Your code does not wait but proceeds to look right away, before the search is done.  Need another Wait" here.

Comment: I suggest you to put a break point in your VBA code and try to debug it step by step. check the IE screen that each operation on the page taking how much amount of time. Try to include the statement to wait for that much or little bit more time. Again try to run the  code without any break point to see whether it is able to fix this issue or not.

Comment: Yes I have done both of your suggests. I even looped and Msgbox on each loop to see the content of every <div> and <span> elements and it never shows the related code I added

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to say by,"it never shows the related code I added". Do you mean your code is not able to locate the correct span element on the page to click it? Please try to correct us by providing the detailed information about your testing result will help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes Deepak, it means that exactly. Code loops through all div and span elements, and it would be supposed to get to some point where it msgbox that specific element in either one of the options, yet it doesn't.

Comment: I try to test your loop code to check whether it is able to find the span element on the web page or not. Based on my testing result, I found that your loop is able to find the span element. https://i.postimg.cc/2ySGg8Xg/282.png I suggest you to post some more HTML around your span if possible. So that we can test if your loop is able to find the span with it or not. It can be possible that it is not able to search if span is child of child of any element.